# Missing right parenthesis in shell command?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make, cat

I'm trying to add a warning message to my makefile. Make is having trouble locating a right parenthesis.

The following is from my GNUmakefile:

```
341  ALIGNED_ACCESS = $(shell cat config.h | $(EGREP) -c "^#define NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS")
342  ifeq ($(ALIGNED_ACCESS),0)
343  $(info WARNING: NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS is not defined in config.h)
344  endif
```

Make complains:

```
$ make
GNUmakefile:341: *** unterminated call to function 'shell': missing ')'.  Stop.
```

I literally shell out 25 other times in the makefile, so I'm not sure why it can't find the right parenthesis for the shell above.

I also moved the command to line 1 to test it, and I got the same message (modulo the line number change). And for fun, I added an unbalanced right parenthesis, but I got the same message.

Why can't make find the right parenthesis?

How can I coerce make into executing the command?

Comment: As an aside, putting `EGREP` in a variable seems misdirected.

Comment: @tripleee - We place `egrep` in a variable so users can override it if/when `egrep` does not perform as expected. What do you recommend?

Comment: For a start, if performance is an issue, lose the [useless `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html). Anyway, I find it hard to imagine a scenario where `egrep` would be too slow for handling a few thousand C source files, or where a regular user would be able to devise a significantly faster replacement.

Comment: @triplee - *"if performance is an issue..."* - no, performance is not an issue. Good point about `cat`... I never thought about it. But what about `egrep`?

Comment: Then what does "not perform as expected" mean? `grep -E` should be portable enough, unless you target markedly pre-POSIX platforms.

Comment: @triplee - we support many popular operating systems going back to the 1990s, from the BSDs through Linux and Unix, including OS X and Solaris, and Windows and its Linux on Windows knock-offs. If you have ever had the pleasure of trying to use, say, `sed -i`, you know exactly why we are concerned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the `#` in the makefile as this starts a comment ...

```
ALIGNED_ACCESS = $(shell cat config.h | $(EGREP) -c "^\#define NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS")
```

Note the '\' before '#'

Comment: Indeed, that was it.... I though that might be it, so I tried using both single and double quotes... But I did not think to try and escape it.

Comment: To be completely candid, the answer should perhaps specifically mention backslash, and/or show an example. With the UUCA fix, try `$(shell grep -Ec "^\#define NO_UNALIGNED_DATA_ACCESS" config.h)`